# JSONModel Invalid JSON data

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, jsonmodel

I have this Json out of ASP MVC API
I have the InvModel and the LotModel

but when I call

```
_InvFeed = [[InvModel alloc] initFromURLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.206/service/api/dto/inventory/1?p=Red%20Globe"
                                        completion:^(JSONModel *model, JSONModelError *err) 
        {
            NSLog(@"Inventory: %@", _InvFeed );
            NSLog(@"Error: %@",err);
        }];
```

I can not figure out this error:

> Error: Error Domain=JSONModelErrorDomain Code=1 **"Invalid JSON data:
>   Attempt to initialize JSONModel object using initWithDictionary:error:
>   but the dictionary parameter was not an 'NSDictionary'."** 
>   UserInfo=0x109075ff0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Invalid JSON data:
>   Attempt to initialize JSONModel object using initWithDictionary:error:
>   but the dictionary parameter was not an 'NSDictionary'.,
>   kJSONModelKeyPath=LotDTO}

[image: JSONData]

and here are the JSONModels for: LotDTO

```
#import "JSONModel.h"

@interface InvLotModel : JSONModel
@property (assign, nonatomic) int lotid;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDate* expdate;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* lotserial;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDate* lastupddate;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString<Optional>* providerlotserial;
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSDecimal* qtyoriginal;
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSDecimal* qtyallocated;
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSDecimal* qtyavailable;
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSDecimal* qtyonhand;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDate* receiptdate;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* linecomment;
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSDecimal* unitcost;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* warehouse;
@end
```

And here the Inventory Model

```
#import "JSONModel.h"
#import "InvLotModel.h"
@protocol InvModel @end
@interface InvModel : JSONModel
@property (assign, nonatomic) int id;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* itemid;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* description;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDate* createdate;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* createuser;
@property (assign, nonatomic) float lastcost;
@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL monitorlevel;
@property (assign, nonatomic) int minlevel;
@property (assign, nonatomic) int maxlevel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* gtin;
@property (assign, nonatomic) float weight;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* uom;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* sizes;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* variety;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString <Optional>* bag;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* style;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* box;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* label;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* commodity;

@property (strong, nonatomic) InvLotModel* LotDTO;
@end
```

Comment: It seems to me the message is clear.  Where are you doing initWithDictionary?

Comment: BTW, what you list is not a dictionary.

Comment: If you see the code at the beginning I am using initFromURLWithString not dictionary.

Comment: So where are you doing initWithDictionary, and what does the dictionary look like?  Your error message says "Attempt to initialize JSONModel object using initWithDictionary:error: but the dictionary parameter was not an 'NSDictionary'".

Comment: Again this is what I could not figure out why?, I never did initWithDictionary see to top code on my post I was using  initFromURLWithString.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two problems:

1) In the `InvModel` class, yo have defined `LotDTO` as a single object, not an array.

2) In the JSON response you have posted, the syntax for `LotDTO` does not seem to me valid JSON. It appears to be an array of `LotDTO` objects, but it does not follow the syntax for JSON arrays (which you can check, for example, [here](http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp)).

Comment: Yes you was right regarding the LotDTO not being defined as array, I was hacking everywhere I miss that one, but I went for test and error and after commented all the properties and un-comenting one by one I found the the property "description" was breaking the feed so I just renamed my JSON to "descrip" and everything works! could be that "description" needs to be pointed as Reserved Word?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to mark any extension property as `Ignore`. I faced such an issue trying to copy the model.

Answer (score 0):

Please replace this

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) InvLotModel* LotDTO;
```

with this

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray<InvLotModel,ConvertOnDemand>* LotDTO;
```

As officials at JSONModel suggest to use ConvertOnDemand to convert NSArray to JSONModelArray in one of their tutorial to avoid error in implenentation.

This may help you : [Click here](http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/how-to-fetch-and-parse-json-by-using-data-models/)